# Data Label Formatting HighCharts Tree Map

Tags: javascript, highcharts, treemap

I am using tree map but the problem is my data label are not formatting properly.

[image]

As you can see the text in the last area is cropped. how can i fix this issue ?

HTML :

```
<div id="divHeatMap" style="width: 1300px; height: 800px"></div>
```

SCRIPT :

```
 $('#divHeatMap').highcharts({
                            colorAxis: {
                                minColor: '#FA0404', // red
                                maxColor: '#08F718' // green
                            },
                            series: [returnJson.Series],
                            title: {
                                text: ''
                            },
                            plotOptions: {
                                treemap: {
                                    //  area: { cropThreshold: 500 },
                                    dataLabels: {
                                        // overflow: 'right',
                                        //  crop: true,
                                        formatter: function () {
                                            return '<b>Name : ' + this.point.name + '</b> ' +
                                                '<br/>' +
                                                '<b>Price : ' + this.point.CurrentPrice + '</b> ' +
                                                '<br/>' +
                                                '<b>Net Change :  ' + this.point.NetChange + '</b>' +
                                                '<br/><b>% Change :' + this.point.PercentageChange + '</b>' +
                                                '<br/>' +
                                                '<b>Value :' + this.point.value + '</b> ' +
                                                '<br/>';
                                            //  return '$' + this.point.name
                                        },
                                        color: 'white'
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        });
```

Comment: You are trying to show a lot of info on a dataLabel. What we do is not show dataLabels at all on the treemap and instead show it in tooltips. Not ideal but trying to guess at the size of the area that we can put a dataLabel in + how long the dataLabel could be is a headache we choose not to worry about. Here is an old example before treemap was official: http://jsfiddle.net/wergeld/06mha391/5/

Comment: It seems that the question is "how can I fit more text in a box than can fit in the box".  I'm not sure there's a good answer for that...

Comment: ok is there any possible if the text goes outside the box it should not show.